# Protobuf files versioning in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, version, grpc, versioning

I writing a `grpc` Interface and messages in a `protobuf` file, eventually I will have breaking changes in the interfaces and messages.

How does one handle `protobuf` versioning in python?

---

In `C#` it is [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/versioning?view=aspnetcore-3.1#version-number-services) to use the optional package specifier with a version number,

And then the package name is combined with the service name to identify a service address.

Something like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package my_grpc_package.v1;
```

```
syntax = "proto3";
package my_grpc_package.v2;
```

However I [read](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#packages) that in python

> In Python, the package directive is ignored, since Python modules are organized according to their location in the file system.

So I am not sure How would I would achieve similar functionality? generate the `grpc` client again in a separate file and named it `my_grpc_package.v2.py` manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The version number can be included into the file path, the gRPC repo itself also uses this way to organize its proto files: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/proto/grpc/health/v1

Comment: seems like they don't do it for [everything](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/proto/grpc/http_over_grpc)

Comment:  I'm struggling to find the reason to do this. Why is adding the version number (which is the major release number if we follow semver) to the package name recommended? Other (non-protobuf) packages don't have the version number in the package.

Comment: Ahh, that's explained on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/versioning?view=aspnetcore-6.0#version-number-services=) : "A way to maintain backwards compatibility while making breaking changes is to publish multiple versions of a service.". Which means you literally have 2 services with different APIs, and you are maintaining both of them. I understand now.